# Log4j2 - Seperate logs for different levels - How do I print just the INFO levels?

Tags: log4j2

How do I print just the INFO levels?

My current log is printing all INFO, WARN, ERROR and FATAL levels to console - I understand why this is happening. (because they are all above INFO)

Is there a way to just specify that just and only just, INFO levels get sent to the console appender and not everything above it?

Currently have the following log4j2 xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="App" packages="">
    <Appenders>

    <File name="logFile" fileName="C:\Users\user\workspace\logs\log.out">
        <PatternLayout>
            <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
    </File>

    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>

</Appenders>
<Loggers>


    <Logger name="com.App" level="info" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="logFile" level="error"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="Console" level="info"/>

    </Logger>

    <Root level="error">
        <AppenderRef ref="logFile" />
    </Root>


</Loggers>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use a ThresholdFilter;

```
<ThresholdFilter level="WARN" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT" />
```

This blocks the WARN level and everything above it. So now it only accepts info.